# Scrollbar not showing, but panel does

Tags: css

I have a table surrounded by an  with the a css class:

```
DIV.scrollableTable {
 overflow-y: scroll;
 height: 100%; 
 width: 100%;  
}
```

when I load the page, the scroll panel is present, but the bar isn't. And in order for me to scroll I have to select everything in the table and move the mouse down. Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Please show some sample HTML as well

Comment: Is it possible the table's width doesn't exceed the width of the screen? What happens if you made the width say...50%?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the scroll bar to show, the content of `DIV.scrollTable` must be higher than "DIV.scrollTable".